# Find and replace a URL with grep/sed/awk?

Tags: grep, replace

Fairly regularly, I need to replace a local url with a live in large WordPress databases. I can do it in TextMate, but it often takes 10+ minutes to complete.

Basically, I have a 10MB+ .sql file and I want to:

Find:   http://localhost:8888/mywebsite

and

Replace with: http://mywebsite.com

After that, I'll save the file and do a mysql import to the local/live servers. I do this at least 3-4 times a week and waiting for Textmate has been a pain. Is there an easier/faster way to do this with grep/sed/awk?

Thanks!

Terry

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sed 's/http:\/\/localhost:8888\/mywebsite/http:\/\/mywebsite.com/g' FileToReadFrom > FileToWriteTo
```

This is running switch (s/) globally (/g) and replacing the first URL with the second.  Forward slashes are escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Takes a fraction of a second to complete.

Answer (score 3):

```
kent$  echo "foobar||http://localhost:8888/mywebsite||fooooobaaaaaaar"|sed 's#http://localhost:8888/mywebsite#http://mywebsite.com#g'
foobar||http://mywebsite.com||fooooobaaaaaaar
```

if you want to do the replace in place (change in your original file)

```
sed -i 's#http://.....#http://mysite#g' input.sql
```

Comment: Great tip to avoid leaning toothpick syndrome.  I assumed from perl you could do this, but it was nice to see confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to replace the `http://`

`sed "s/localhost:8888/www.my-awesome-page.com/g" input.sql > output.sql`